# PHP simple "if page id is xyz, display this <div>"

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

im not familiar with PHP, but I'd like to create in Wordpress something like:

```
if page id="123"
show this -> <div class"option one">my content</div>

if page id="124"
show this -> <div class"option two">my other content</div>

if page id="125"
show this -> <div class"option three">my other content 2</div>
```

The code will be placed in my page.php

So what is the exact php code?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by page id?

Comment: This was lazy to close without at least giving a simple explanation. It would have been more productive to help ask clarifying questions, add edits, or post a link rather than just close. This is an easy answer, anyone know knows ANYTHING about PHP could have answered instead of just voting to close.

Answer (score 5):

for example you have `page_id` `123`, `124` ...etc then
Do it as:

```
<?php   if ( is_page(123) ) { 
?>
 <div class="option one">my content</div>


<?php } elseif( is_page(124) ) {

?>
 <div class="option one">abc content</div>

<?php } 
else {
echo  '<div class="option one">any content</div>';
}

?>
```

Comment: you missed `=` in `class"option.."` i had update it.

Comment: @RoyalBg I think he's missing a `for($i = 0; $i < 1; $i++){` block somewhere for this to work right. Perhaps also some `if (!false)` blocks.